# Does a large number of arguments in the WHERE IN() clause affect performance in sqlite?

Tags: performance, sqlite, select, where-in

```
SELECT * FROM atable WHERE some_id IN(3,5,2)
```

This is ok. But what if I have to pass 1000 IDs? Will it slow down the query?

`some_id` is always indexed.

I know I probably shouldn't pass that number of arguments, but I need to get a large number of records from a table, then get related records from 2 other tables. If I use JOINs the returned array is huge. So I figured I should just do the main query, then two other queries for the related tables using the IN clause where I pass the IDs from the main query

Comment: Why not using `INNER JOIN` with first table and (rest of two)?

Comment: no, in most dbs it will not be a prob, but - keep in mind that a) 32k is a typical (or resonable) max size for sql, b) I am sure there is a better answer if you give a better question

Comment: by 32K you mean that the query string can have up to 32 KB? I think that's more than enough for me, I only need like 2-3K :)